# how can & where can i edit the InputSplit size in CDH4.7. By default it is 64 MB, but i want to mention it as 1MB

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

How can and where can i edit the Input Split size in CDH4.7 By default it is 64 MB but i want to mention it as 1MB because my MR job is running slow and i want increase the speed of MR job. i guess need to edit cor-site property IO.file.buffer.size but CDH4.7 is not allowing me to edit as it is read only.
just reapeating the question below the get my question posted 
How can and where can i edit the Input Split size in CDH4.7 By default it is 64 MB but i want to mention it as 1MB because my MR job is running slow and i want increase the speed of MR job. i guess need to edit cor-site property IO.file.buffer.size but CDH4.7 is not allowing me to edit as it is read only.

Answer (score 0):

The parameter "mapred.max.split.size" which can be set per job individually is what you looking for.

You don't change "dfs.block.size" because Hadoop Works better with a small number of large files than a large number of small files. One reason for this is that FileInputFormat generates splits in such a way that each split is all or part of a single file. If the file is very small ("small" means significantly smaller than an HDFS block) and there are a lot of them, then each map task will process very little input, and there will be a lot of them (one per file), each of which imposes extra bookkeeping overhead. Compare a 1gb file broken into sixteen 64mb blocks, and 10.000 or so 100kb files. The 10.000 files use one map each, and the job time can be tens or hundreds of times slower than the equivalent one with a single input file and 16 map tasks.

You can change it directly from within the command using `-D mapred.max.split.size=..` from command line and don't necessarily change any file permanently.